# How to change colors for multiple charts in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the c**olors of the different columns on a chart** for each of my charts and I have **about 50 charts** so I would rather not do this manually.

I have looked on other forums and seen to use:

```
For Each cht In Sheets("GraphData").ChartObjects
```

When I run that I get a **type-mismatch error**.

I don't quite understand why it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
Sub changestuff()

Dim cht As Chart, ChtObj As ChartObject, wks As Worksheet


For Each cht In Sheets("GraphData").ChartObjects
cht.Legend.Delete
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(5).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the exception with its stack trace.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Have you tried the following to skip the error? 
`For Each cht In Workheets("GraphData").ChartObjects`  because ("GraphData") belongs to Worksheets and it could cause type-mismatch

Comment: juanmajmjr I tried that but it still gives me the same error. And R3uK I get the error at the For Each cht in Sheets line at the top, so the loop never runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type mismatch is because the items in `Sheets("GraphData").ChartObjects` are ChartObjects not Charts.  It looks like you want the top of your loop to be

```
For Each ChtObj In Sheets("GraphData").ChartObjects
    set cht = ChtObj.chart
```

It my tests that got rid of the mismatch error.

You can test the kind of object you'll be back from an iterator by starting with a `Variant` or an `Object` and then you can change your declaration.